# How to trigger multibranch downstream job with jobname/{env.BRANCH_NAME}

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I've 2 multibranch jenkins pipeline jobs connecting same github project. I'm triggering first MB job ex. dev. branch, now on success of this job I want to trigger second MB job with same branch name. (I've separate Jenkinsfile fot both MB job).

I've tried below options but didn't work:

(1)

```
build  job: 'jobName', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH_NAME', value: env.BRANCH_NAME]]
```

This gives me error "Waiting for non-job items is not supported"

(2)

```
build  job: 'jobName/${branch_name}'
```

This gives me jobname/${branch_name} does not exist means variable here is not resolving, I've created this variable in environment directive

Simple jobName/dev if I'd give hardcode in Jenkinsfile then it's working, but I'd need it with automatically selecting branch name.

please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution for this issue:

In the jenkinsfile triggering pipeline job with gitParameter:

```
build   job: 'jobName', parameters: [gitParameter(name: 'GITBRANCH', value: env.BRANCH_NAME)]
```

Installed "git parameter" plugin, and configure in job which is being triggered in jenkinsfile

```
parameters {
    gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'GITBRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
    }
```

And calling this parameter while checkout code

```
stage("Checkout Branch wise"){
            steps{
                git branch: "${params.GITBRANCH}", url: 'https://xxx/xxx/xxxx.git'
            }
        }
```

which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use variables inside your string you need to use double quotes, example:

```
$"BRANCH_NAME"
```

From the groovy docs:

> "Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals,
> apart from single and triple-single-quoted strings. "

More here:
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#all-strings

An alternative could also be to use concatenation:

```
build job:'job/'+somebranchvariable, parameters:[string(name: 'BUILD_NAME', value: build_name)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this format, it is working.

```
build(job: "JOBNAME" + "/" + "${BRANCH_NAME}".replaceAll('/', '%2F'))
```

Forward slash (`/`) is converted to `%2f` in the job name:
It’s a common practice to use a forward slash (`/`) when creating feature branches within developer teams, so whenever a new Pipeline gets created automatically with the creation of a new branch, `/` will get converted into `%2f`.

Whenever you are referencing the branch name in the job or calling any job as a downstream, you will have to make sure of this conversion. Look at the below example where we are trying to call a downstream project.